# WP7 WebBrowser (http 401) authentication?

Tags: windows-phone-7, authentication, browser

Does anyone knows how can we proceed to authenticate a user via the WP7 embedded WebBrowser control ?

It's working perfectly when i'm using the external IE browser of the emulator but in a WebBrowser control there is no prompt to fill username/password/domain informations and i have a page telling me "We're having trouble displaying this page".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using a different Uri for the WebBrowser and WebBrowserTask? Or maybe you need to modify the IsScriptEnabled property.

Comment: I'm using the same Uri for both. I have also change the IsScriptEnabled to True value but it's still the same...

Comment: Well, then the problem is non-trivial and you would need to share some code.